# Social Login Integration With Xamarin.Forum

Tags: facebook-graph-api, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using **Xamarin.Auth** For Authenticate user. I want to Authenticate Facebook User..Please check i have defined scope in code true or not.
My code for Authenticate given Below:

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (clientId: App.Instance.OAuthSettings.ClientId, 
                             scope:"publish_stream,user_about_me,read_stream,email",
                                    authorizeUrl: new Uri (App.Instance.OAuthSettings.AuthorizeUrl), 
                                    redirectUrl: new Uri (App.Instance.OAuthSettings.RedirectUrl)); 
        auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => 
        {
            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                App.Instance.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
                // Use eventArgs.Account to do wonderful things
                App.Instance.SaveToken(eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"]);
            }
            else
            {                 
            }
        };
```

Please Help me Solve this Issue. i have attached image . please tell me what i missing.Thanks in Advance.
[Facebook error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki9pg.png)